# “Was there not” or “Wasn’t there” - what’s the difference?

Tags: questions, conditionals

Is there a difference between “Was there not” or “Wasn’t there” in the meaning?

Example: Was there not an emptiness…?. Or can be interchangeably used for the same “ Wasn’t there an emptiness…?”

Or is it some kind of conditional question?

Thank you

Comment: The only difference is that _wasn't there_ is informal. Most people would use it in ordinary conversation.

Comment: @KateBunting - there are parts of Britain where the 'was there not...' form would be the normal, informal form.

Comment: Thank you @KateBunting, @MichaelHarvey!